# Web audio - How to call a function based on current Time?

Tags: audio, web, timing, web-audio-api

I was wondering could you please help. I am using the web audio to play music for a certain amount of time. After around 90 seconds (depending on length of song), i want to call my loadAndPlay() function again to repeat play. The function will be called every 90 seconds or so.

I would like to use the same method to trigger effects at the same time, using Tuna.js

it seems that this will not work:

```
if (context.currentTime > 90*totalPlays)
{
loadAndPlay();
}
```

i have also tried using this method:

```
if (time > 90*totalPlays){
        source.onended = function()
     {
  console.log("End. starting again");
   loadAndPlay();
   totalPlays++
      }
```

time will usually be around 90 and 105. This works sometimes but not all the time unfortunately. I would like to steer away from 'source.onended' anyway as it is unreliable.

the same idea using effects, cueing a delay for 15 seconds

```
while (context.currentTime > 90 && context.currentTime < 105){
delay.wetLevel = 10
}
```

if anyone could point out where i'm going wrong that would be fantastic. thank you!

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding how JavaScript works. It would be easier to tell if you provided more context for your code (a complete example, which you think should work, would be best). But your last bit of code is a strong sign: if it runs when context.currentTime is 91, it will just spin for 14 seconds, locking up the browser. You should never do that kind of thing.

Comment: Also, I'm curious why you said that onended is unreliable. Is there a bug in some browser?